# Apply mods before baking?

Tags: modifiers, texture-painting, baking

I've done a model in blender, and also did retopology and UV map of it.
For retopo, I added mirror, subsurf and shrinkwrap modifiers (in that order). Now, I've got 2 questions:

-Should I apply those modifiers before baking? When should modifiers be applied?

-What should i do first: baking or painting the model? Does the order matter?

Thank u

Comment: You don't ever have to bake (unless you're doing game development)—it'll just make things render faster. You'll have to rebake it if you change anything you've baked, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend on painting the model with non-symmetrical details, then you will want to apply the mirror modifier at some point before painting and setting an image texture. The mirror should be applied before baking if you are getting details from the source object - this also will help avoid seams in your normal map.